# Discord.py. Не работают слэш-команды

Tags: python, discord.py

Слэш команды не появляются в дереве команд. В консоли вылезает ошибка:

```
  "discord.app_commands.errors.MissingApplicationID:  Client does not have an application_id set. Either the function was
    called before on_ready was called or application_id was not passed
    to the Client constructor."
```

```
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name = "test")
async def test(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id="айди моего сервера"))

bot.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Как это можно пофиксить? Пробовал прописывать команды через `@app.command()` , но результат тот же самый...

Comment: По моему опыту - никак. Лучше использовать другие библиотеки, там проще.

Comment: Дам вам совет перейти на disnake, там с этим куда проще.

Comment: Я бы просто юзал ``@bot.hybrid_command`` или ``@bot.command``, а не создавал новый tree... А либа неплохая в целом, если разобраться)

Comment: @DaYa, я думаю, вы правы. Действительно, disnake куда удобнее discord.py. Проблема данной либы в том, что отсутствуют интерактивные ивенты (ивенты для интерактивного клиента), а они составляют около 15 % кода.  Благодарю Вас за совет!